# spring dynamic views of different directories

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

this is my first post in stackoverflow and also i'm new to spring. this is my question(please don't mind my language)

this is my folder structure of the project in netbeans(i cant post images yet because i have no 10 reputations)

```
    WEB-INF
      views
        sales
          sales_invoice.jsp
          sales_order.jsp
          sales_order_list.jsp
          sales_invoice_list.jsp
        purchase
          purchase_order.jsp
          grn.jsp
        accounts
          account_list.jsp
      web.xml
      spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml
```

I want to invoke jsps inside any directory under view folder using spring i try to do in this way but i was unable to do that under my knowledge. (In the web xml i use InternalViewResolver and also i used annotation to define controllers and requestMappings)

please tell me how to invoke thease jsp using this way or another way because my final project is waiting till your possible responses 
Thank You

Comment: Please post some code of what you have done so far after that we can help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i am assuming that you have created `mvc-dispatch-servlate.xml` in which you have configuration like this.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

your controller code should be like this if want to access `sales > sales_invoice.jsp`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/sales")
public class SalesController{

   @RequestMapping(value="/sales-invoice", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String salesInvoice(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

      return "sales/sales_invoice";
   }

}
```

Comment: oh thanks brother its working for me thanks a lot and i have another one to solve if you have a free time please help me for this one also. this is the question, can we use sub directories to store controller classes inside the base-controller-package? if it is possible please tell me how will do that...

Comment: I haven't done something like that before, but i think it is possible.You should post another question,may be someone can help you.